# Change background image width with checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple Chrome extension that injects some html into a game webpage that lets a user customize the background image of the webpage. It stores the URL of the image with setlocalstorage so that when they return to the game the custom background image is still there. I've included some CSS that forces the image to fit the width of the browser window. This satisfies most users but, there are a few that have requested I allow them to turn off the width-matching feature. What I'd like to do is add a check box to allow the user to turn off the width adjustment.

I'm thinking some sort of "if the box is checked apply this class to the body tag" sort of thing but, I can't seem to figure it out.

If someone could show me how to accomplish this I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It would also be nice to see your code in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Attach an onchange event listener to the checkbox that checks the value of 'checked' for your checkbox element and adds/removes the class:

```
yourCheckboxElement.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    document.body.classList[this.checked ? "add" : "remove"]("someClass");
    /* save value of this.checked to localStorage here */
});
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/8RC2m/1/

Comment: AWESOME! This one worked great and integrated nicely with my existing code. Rather than changing the color to blue I just created a class that sets: background-size: auto !important

Comment: Is there any way to retain the checked or unchecked state when the user leaves the page?

Comment: Store the value of 'checked' using localStorage when the value changes. Restore it upon load and add the class to the body if the stored value is true.

Comment: I understand how to set localStorage and recall it when it's from a text field but, not the state of a checkbox.   :(

Comment: You can store any value in localStorage. The syntax is the same. `localStorage.setItem('checkboxValue', this.checked);`

Comment: ...but then how do you recall that state when the visitor returns?

Comment: I get that I can do checked=true on the tag for the checkbox itself but, how do I instead use the "state" stored in localstorage?

Comment: How are you creating the check box element? You may be able to set the checked property during creation. Worst case, you can check local storage after adding the checkbox input tag to the page and then set it's checked property accordingly. checkboxElement.checked = localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue') ;

Answer (score 1):

Change css when checkbox is marked:

```
$("#new").click(function() {
    if (this.checked){
       $(this).closest('p').addClass('white');
    } else {
       $(this).closest('p').removeClass('white');
    } 
});
```

add styles:

```
.white {
   color: white;
}
```

That might work for you, no?

Additionally,

```
$(":checkbox").attr("autocomplete", "on");
```

Comment: This might help with cache. http://usejquery.com/blog/create-self-caching-website-ready-offline-usage-html5-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your width adjustment code in a css class like `width-adjustment`. Then try something like this:

```
if ($('#IdOfYourCheckBox').is(":checked") == true){
    $("#ElementToChange").removeClass('width-adjustment');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have requested JavaScript only so i will avoid jQuery, try something like this:

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
if (document.getElementById('checkbox-id').checked){
    b.className +=" yourclass";
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to check if the chkbox is checked or not.

```
(function( $ ){
 $.fn.check = function( handler ) {
 if (handler) {
  this.each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        handler.call(this); 
       $(this).closest('p').addClass('white');
      }
    });
  }); 
 } else {
  this.each(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
    $(this).change();
    $(this).closest('p').addClass('white');
  });
 }
};

 $.fn.uncheck = function( handler ) {
 if (handler) {
  this.each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      if (!$(this).attr('checked')) {
        handler.call(this); 
       $(this).closest('p').removeClass('white');
      }
    });
  }); 
  } else {
  this.each(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
    $(this).change();
       $(this).closest('p').removeClass('white');
  });
  }
 };
})( jQuery );
```